# Incoming email setup for Document Libraries

Tags: document-library, email, smtp

I am confused as I read documents on this subject. Here are some questions...

1. Do I need to setup SMTP on all the SharePoint servers (we have 2WFEs and 1 App)?
2. Do I need separate email address setup in Exchange for different doc libraries?
3. If yes to # 2 , then which SharePoint service account(s) should have access to this/these emails?

Thanks

Comment: What SharePoint version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. You only need to set it up on one of your servers
2. Yes each document library will have a different email address
3. Will be the account that the Sharepoint Timer job service is running as, as this is what processes the emails coming in and then saves them to the library